# UISearchbar: Diplaying last inputs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchbar in my application and would like to have a popover when typing text that shows me the last search-inputs. Do I have to implement this by myself, or is this included in the UISearchbar and needs to be activated?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement this yourself

Comment: Before reinventing the wheel: Is there any code in the web, that I can reuse?

Comment: I found a sample by apple: Have a look at ToolbarSearch-project